# Android Studio shows warning: Element merge is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I create custom view based on LinearLayout. Class extends the LinearLayout class, in layout I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <merge>
        some staff here
    </merge>
</layout>
```

Android Studio shows the the warning `Element merge is not allowed here`, but app works.

What's wrong?

Comment: As I understand, use <merge> as root tag. <layout> is tag for all layout data, not only layout itself. Look at here: https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#writing_expressions

Comment: I don't think that's the solution. If I make the `<merge>` tag the root and put `<layout>` inside it, I get a warning that the layout isn't allowed there and it refuses to compile. At least it compiles when `<layout>` is the root.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's just a glitch in Android studio. Even the official documentation has `merge` as a direct child of `layout`: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Edit: I filed a bug there: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=286406&thanks=286406&ts=1490873944

Edit2: Bug is fixed \o/ in AS 3.5 Canary 12

Comment: it says that __it's not__ supported

Comment: @Shujito can you please share your source ? the documentation says: `Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element.`

This means <include> cannot be a child of <merge>. It doesn't say anything about <merge> being a child of <layout>.

Do I miss something ? Please clarify.

Comment: Have I tried what ? I tried adding <merge> as a child of <layout> and I get a warning in Android Studio as the OP says. I don't see anywhere in the documentation where it says this use case is not supported. If you found it in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html, please copy paste the relevant section here. Thanks.

Comment: @Shujito yes but it's not supported because "Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element", not because data binding doesn't support merge altogether (at least according to this doc).

Answer (score -2):

Actually you dont need merge at all here since you have layout in root for databisnig.
<merge> tag here is redundant!

> **Use the <merge> Tag**
>
> The  tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view
> hierarchy when including one layout within another

From : [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge)

Layout as merge wont be drawn and system ignores them during drawing.

To approve that I did tracking layouts by Hierarchy View in Android Device Monitor for layout .. it doesn't exist which means its doing the same job as merge tag . you can check it by yourself!

Hope that may help..

Comment: Just tried this and got this error ```Error:Only one layout element and one data element are allowed. /Users/davethomas/dev*****t.xml has 3``` You can not have more than one element in a layout except for the data element.

Comment: that is true. you need to set all content under one layout. under Layout

Answer (score -5):

Make `<merge>` be the first tag in the file.

Comment: I can not. If I do this then bindind file will not be generated.