# Android: How to deal with more than one Root Tags in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

So I was making a common Layout to include it in several classes and while doing so, I used `<merge>` tag as it helps in removing extra `ViewGroups`. There is no problem with it but if I also add `<layout>` tag for DataBinding then it shows a warning:

**Element merge is not allowed here**

The way I put it:

```
<layout>
    <merge>
      <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
    </merge>
</layout>
```

OR

```
 <merge>
     <layout>
      <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
     </layout>
 </merge>
```

Either way, it shows a warning as there can only be one Root Tag.

So, my question is:

How can we use two root tags together like say in this case where you have to merge and use data binding along with it? What is the best practice?

Comment: I think in binding there should be only one root tag and you can include multiple layouts inside that

Comment: The binding doesn't bind included elements by itself unless you add <layout> tag in them.

Comment: yes you need to add layout tag inside included layout also.. and to access them binding.included.etUser..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43116720/8089770

Comment: Oh, I get it. It works though, yes. So it's just a glitch as they didn't manage this special case completely.  Anyway, thank you.